# splunk vs cordys operations intelligence

Tags: bigdata, splunk

Can Cordys Operations Intelligence (COI) be an alternative to Splunk?

I have not used COI, however looking at the videos and documents it seems very similar to what Splunk can do in terms of providing Operations Intelligence from real time big data.

Comment: I'd recommend Boole & Babbage "Command/Post".

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually Cordys Operations Intelligence (COI) and Splunk differ in a way that COI uses Excel as calculation engine. In COI, real-time data is fed to an (existing) Excel sheet and results can be visualized and monitored in applications like SharePoint. Splunk has its own indexed data store and calculation engine. This means that a business user or domain owner needs to learn a new tool in stead of simply using the well known office applications like Excel and SharePoint.

(Author works at Cordys)

Comment: You should disclose your association with Cordys in your answer.